# Allure report in azure devops with e2e tests result

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, playwright, allure

I am using azure devops with playwright e2e tests, but I do not know how could I publish the allure report inside the pipeline (local is good)

I installed the extension, the pipeline is good just no generate allur report
part of my yml:

```
jobs:
- job: AutomatedTests
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14.x'
      cache: 'npm'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: npm install
  - script: npx playwright install --with-deps

    displayName: "run the test"
    condition: succeeded()
  - script: npm run smoke
  - script: npm run generate

  - task: AllureGenerate
    inputs:
      resultsDir: 'allure-results'
      targetDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Can anybody help me pls?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you export your test results in a compatible framework type, you could use the `PublishTestResults` task to do what you need. `mergeTestResults` should be used if you have more than one result file that you need to be uploaded.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: publish unit test results
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: 'file*.extension'
    searchFolder: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    testRunTitle: Unit test results for $(Build.BuildNumber)
    buildConfiguration: debug
    mergeTestResults: true
```

Based on your export format you should select between
`'JUnit' # Options: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, xUnit, cTest`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml